# Curses background color not working in iTerm2 with TERM=xterm

Tags: python, curses, iterm2

I have the following code that draws a small window with a message using `curses`.

```
import curses
import time

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLUE)
window = curses.newwin(15, 60)
window.bkgd(' ', curses.color_pair(1))
window.addstr(7, 1, 'Hello')
window.refresh()
time.sleep(2)
curses.endwin()
```

I expect the background color to be blue, but the behavior is not consistent in iTerm2. With `TERM=screen`, I get the expected output:
[image]

When `TERM=xterm` though, spaces are not painted:
[image]

If I use a different character for the background, it's painted correctly. What could be the issue?

I'm using Python 3 and iTerm2 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that tmux does not support the "back color erase" feature assumed in the xterm terminal description.

Further reading:

- [My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Why do Vim colors look different inside and outside of tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348771/why-do-vim-colors-look-different-inside-and-outside-of-tmux/349040#349040)