# How to reset background color of characters after calling addstr with color_pair()

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I don't quite understand how the color control in curses is supposed to work. Consider this example:

```
import curses

TIMEOUT = 100
HEIGHT = 80
WIDTH = 200


curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
window = curses.newwin(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 0, 0)
window.timeout(TIMEOUT)
window.keypad(1)
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
window.border(0)

curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLUE)

while True:
    window.erase()

    window.addstr(0, 0, 'line 1', curses.color_pair(1))
    window.addstr(1, 0, 'line 2')

    event = window.getch()

    if event == ord('q'):
        break


curses.endwin()
```

The output is:

```
line 1 << red on blue
line 2 << white on black
```

Why is line 2 having a black background without me having specified so? It does not have one if I comment out `window.addstr(0, 0, 'line 0', curses.color_pair(1))`.

Comment: Actually I get white-on-black for that line either way.  There are a few pitfalls which can be explained by (a) which terminal emulator and (b) which value of `TERM`.

Comment: Well, I want it to use what ever configuration it had used before line 1. But Term value is xterm-256color and the emulator is iTerm2. Actually I just spotted a question ona similar problem with iTerm2 and xterm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214987/curses-background-color-not-working-in-iterm2-with-term-xterm?rq=1

Comment: If you're using tmux, that could be the same problem (making this a duplicate).

Comment: How can I tell if I am? And what emulator can I use that works properly with curses?

Comment: You said you're using iTerm2.  Perhaps you selected some color theme or palette which is confusing ncurses about the actual color on the screen.  By the way, you should add clarifications to your question rather than as comments.